# Emulate sd card in windows

Tags: android

I wanted to emulate an sd-card. I am working on windows vista operating system. I tried to emulate one. But there was a permission denial shown in DDMS and also the sd-card is not shown as detected when I checked the gallery. Can you please say the complete steps for emulating a fake sd card in windows. i want to emulate a fake sd-card from a file, not by creating one in AVD by just putting a size like 500 mb and adding sd-card support. I need it in the other way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: i took an sd card image file which was created on a linux system from my friend's computer

Comment: Start by creating an AVD with sdcard

Comment: hey do u know how to emulate a fake sd card from a file, not by creating one in AVD by just putting a size like 500 mb and adding sd card support ...i need it in the other way

Comment: Create the AVD and then replace the sdcard.img file

Comment: i did that ..but when i checked in the ddms there is permission issue..it shows d------- .any idea

Comment: da poorimonae ninakku vallom ariyamo??